# Ubuntu 14.10 Install Fails to Boot on Gigabyte PC

Tags: boot, system-installation

When I boot my bootable ubuntu 14.10 USB on my GIGABYTE H97-HD3 motherboard with i5 4690 CPU, 16GB RAM and GTX750 graphics, I selected Install Now option and it shortly get stuck at the following lines:

```
[2.974542] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c
[2.974593] nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] failed to create 0x18000717, -22
[2.974657] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
```

Would appreciate if you could let me know what I could try...

Answer (score 0):

Did the IMAGE ISO download and write perfect?

I've had many times the ISO download was corrupted / forged.

Also I have 2 gigabyte PCs here both identical, one installs runs UBU perfectly the other not at all - its a mystery to me

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I actually re-written the USB again but it did not help. I used another USB as well

Answer (score 0):

I would try another version or another Linux of choice

Plenty of great distros out there, I customise my ubuntu so much that really I may as well use a diff distro like Arch or something and make it the way I want :p  I'm still a leaner though but what I always do is about 100 terminal commands removing the spyware / backdoors.

When I say spyware I mean like zietgeist and things that help hackers.
And backdoors such as VNC, I know officially its not a backdoor but its security features are easily bypassed by a hacker this is well known so it may as well be a back door lol

I only realised because it was publisheed how to bypass vnc secuyrity in a linux magazine I read!

Sorry I'm going off topic,
I would suggest trying LUBUNTU, LXLE, ZORIN-OS  pick a distro that looks up your street.  If your not very clued up (like me, im a noob) then deffo go with stable release of LINUX MINT ;-)